# Google App Engine + Android project + Java Backend App

Tags: android, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I´m a programming student and I´ve been trying to learn Google App Endpoint by my own. Please someone can guide me through the steps that I must follow to provide a datastore in the cloud for an android application that i already developed or tell me what I´m doing wrong? I have an Android project with SQLite to save data. Now I want to change that and store the information in the cloud. If I do right click on the project, Google-> Generate app engine backend, I got the following error:
PS. I don´t know nothing about phyton or maven. I want to develop in Java with eclipse. 
Thanks.

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-06-11 09:18:22.600
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/EasyBuy/res' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.members(Container.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.members(Container.java:249)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$7.run(Sdk.java:1485)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2014-06-11 09:18:22.601
!MESSAGE Resource '/EasyBuy/res' does not exist.

!ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm_backend 4 0 2014-06-11 09:20:19.713
!MESSAGE Unexpected Exception
!STACK 0
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does indicate that there is some problem in the URL that you have specified for accessing the endpoint. Typically if the url is not well formed (protocol missing, a space somewhere, slashes missing,etc) - then this is likely to occur.

Check the following things:

- From your Android application, trace out the endpoint call that you are trying to make
- Check out the generated client classes and where the URL value is being used. It is likely to be defined as a constant above and which you should modify to point to your server.